# SQL query with optional parameters in a related table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a schema similar to this:

```
Person
----------------
Id (PK)
Name

EventRegistration
----------------
EventId (PK, FK)
PersonId (PK, FK)
DateRegistered

-- EDIT: Note that a single person can registered for multiple events.
```

I need to write a query that searches for names of all people who registered for any events that occurred within a provided date range (i.e. `DateRegistered` should fall within `DateRangeStart` and `DateRangeEnd`). The trick is, the input parameters are optional. So you could define both, only start date, only end date, or neither. These would be interpreted, respectively, as "everything within this range," "everything on/after this date," "everything on/before this date," and "all people regardless of any event registrations."

So I came up with something that works, but I was wondering if I could get some help improving this:

```
-- Assume parameters @DateRangeStart and @DateRangeEnd (both date) are provided by user input

SELECT p.Name
FROM Person p
WHERE 
    (@DateRangeStart IS NULL OR EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 PersonId
        FROM EventRegistration
        WHERE PersonId = p.Id
            AND DateRegistered >= @DateRangeStart
            AND (@DateRangeEnd IS NULL OR DateRegistered <= @DateRangeEnd)
        )
    ) AND
    (@DateRangeEnd IS NULL OR EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 PersonId
        FROM EventRegistration
        WHERE PersonId = p.Id
            AND (@DateRangeStart IS NULL OR DateRegistered >= @DateRangeStart)
            AND DateRegistered <= @DateRangeEnd
        )
    )
```

Comment: I think this homework question gets posted here weekly. You can probably find the answer with a solid search.

Comment: Mine isn't a homework question, but a simplified scenario of a problem I'm trying to solve. Either way, I wasn't sure how to search for it. If you have some links, that'd be great.

Comment: If what you've got works, in what way do you want it improved? If you just want a general code-review, try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Blorgbeard, the where clause feels repetitive and convoluted. I was hoping for a better/cleaner way.

Comment: http://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.Name
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN EventRegistration e
ON p.Id = e.PersonId
WHERE (@DateRangeStart IS NULL OR DateRegistered >= @DateRangeStart)
AND (@DateRangeEnd IS NULL OR DateRegistered <= @DateRangeEnd)
```

Comment: This is the cleanest answer and what gets me the most to what I need. The only thing missing is `distinct` so that it doesn't return multiple rows for the same person in the case if they registered for multiple events. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A more modified, clean way, would be to boolean the where clause.

```
declare @DateRangeStart datetime,  @DateRangeEnd datetime
set @DateRangeStart = null
set @DateRangeEnd = null

select 
    Name
    ,Title
    ,DateRegistered
From
    Person p
    left join
        EventRegistration er on
        er.PersonID = p.ID
    left join
        Event e on
        e.id = er.EventID
where
    (er.DateRegistered >= @DateRangeStart or @DateRangeStart is null)
    and
    (er.DateRegistered <= @DateRangeEnd or @DateRangeEnd is null)
```

Comment: based on OP, there is no need to inner join Event table, OP doesn't need data from there.

Comment: Correct, also, I need to be able to return data from Person table even if a person doesn't have any registrations (in the event the input parameters are null).

Comment: See @PawelCz, the OP changes requirements again. That's why i did the join

Comment: Change to left join @Jiveman and that'll bring back the people--see the edit. If you don't want the dates, then you can drop the last join. I just added everything that you could possibly want.

Comment: No change in requirements. It was described in original post with "all people regardless of any event registrations." Thanks, looking now.

Comment: @Jiveman, so just remove left join Event table and do not select Title, and this will work for you as expected. Then upvote answer or even accept...

Comment: Then adding that table to the schema wasn't necessary and the [M in MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) wasn't truly minimal. Since you did add it, I made assumptions it would be needed in the larger scope (later in code).

Comment: Fair enough, I've updated the table to simplify the example. Also, added a comment clarifying that the EventRegistration table can contain multiple rows for the same person, if they registered for different events. Not really a new requirement as the table keys imply that, but I should have pointed it out. So the left join could return multiple rows for the same person, but a `distinct` should fix that, I believe.

Comment: the left join would then have a row for each registration, but removing the join only looking for the people would, as you said, get what you want which is just the names @Jiveman

Answer (score 1):

Since NULL comparisons do not take advantage of indexes, I would replace the null parameters with valid dates and then use a simple join. It should be fast.

```
@DateRangeStart = Coalesce(@DateRangeStart , MinDate)
@DateRangeEnd = Coalesce(@DateRangeEnd , MaxDate)

select distinct p.name
from Person p join EventRegistration e on p.personId = e.personId and
     e.DateRegistered  between @DateRangeStart  and @DateRangeEnd
```

Another option if you can use dynamic SQL:

```
query=  select distinct p.name
        from Person p join EventRegistration e 
                  on p.personId = e.personId

if DateRangeStart != null query += 'and DateRegistered >= @DateRangeStart '
if DateRangeEnd  != null query += 'and DateRegistered <= @DateRangeEnd  '

executeQuery(...)
```

Comment: I like your comment about NULL comparisons and indexes, but the inner join would miss people who don't have any registrations.

Comment: You're right, this part of the specification is not covered "all people regardless of any event registrations."